# Papyrus is not showing the existing diagram

Tags: installation, eclipse-luna, papyrus

I have installed eclipse luna (Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)) and corresponding papyrus, but facing problem with diagram view. When I am trying to open existing diagram, nothing is showing ([image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRaPf.png)). But the diagram is working fine on another device ([image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpl2P.png)). I have already uninstalled twice and installed again. Help is needed to view diagram in papyrus.

Comment: Why are you using a release of Eclipse which is 6 years and 13 releases old?

Comment: I tried 2020 version, but I was facing the same problem. So, decided to try old version. Now after using 2019 version, it's working. thank you for your response.